# Can I test/determine all decryption types on an unkown filetype. I do have the password

Tags: hash, file-encryption, compression, file-types

I have a file that's nearly 200Mb.  It was reportedly packed/encrypted with Kruptos 2.  But it has a `.~enc` extension.  The header of the file is pure gibberish.  Running `file` says it's `data` running mimetype says it's an `application/octet-stream`.  The only thing that looks like a way to identify the file is at the end of the file.  It looks like it may be a checksum.  Here's what I gathered from the hex editor at the end of the file.

```
786D4532D08A6A06F14D78EA11C648AC6615C025727D1294AA08F43862CBE529©9AA799BC68761F45F3360FEE03D88665©none©F75C7BCC8FB7E449636AE9E3CB81BC8018FCBF307DE1A881765C0A1CBCB65339©193971605©11©3©0©2©32©0© 202©<tkk>
```

My other hex editor shows the copyright symbols as dots

```
786D4532D08A6A06F14D78EA11C648AC6615C025727D1294AA08F43862CBE529.9AA799BC68761F45F3360FEE03D88665.none.F75C7BCC8FB7E449636AE9E3CB81BC8018FCBF307DE1A881765C0A1CBCB65339.193971605.11.3.0.2.32.0. 202.<tkk>
```

Is there a way I can run a decrypt command with trying all the available encryption types using the password I have?  Or at least identify how this file was made and what it is?

One odd thing, I ran `df -T myfile.~enc` and it says ext4 type filesystem.  I tried to mount it but that didn't work.  So maybe that's just a fluke.

Oh, maybe the file name would be a hint.  It's `021405631868CFACCB0C965D0AF04738ABDCB012CEEAC9C583B2A49CDFEE75BE296b.~enc`

Comment: This question is fundamentally unanswerable.  A well-encrypted file is indistinguishable from random data without knowledge of the key or existing meta-data (which there appears to be none) that explains how it was encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stackexchange.  This question can't be answered by security experts; you need to contact the person who generated the encrypted file and/or learn how to use Kruptos 2.  This site isn't for supporting how to use specific applications like Kruptos 2.  The extension of `.~enc` tells little by itself.  `enc` is a common extension for encrypted files, but `~enc` doesn't seem to be a common convention; though as users are always free to rename files.  And possibly you have a case where the original file was `blah.~` and became `blah.~enc` when it just appended `enc` to the file.  I'm not familiar with Kruptos 2.

The `file` utility saying `data` just indicates that the file seems to have binary data (that is not an executable), as opposed to ASCII or unicode plaintext.  The mimetype application/octet-stream is simply stating that it is a stream of bytes (octets) and that there's no meta-data it can infer about what created it.

`df -T file` doesn't tell you anything relevant -- it just states that the file is stored on a partition that is [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) (df doesn't tell you anything about the specific file, it only tells you about the partition that the file is being stored on).

Hexeditors only show printable ASCII characters in the right hand column showing the decoded text.  They generally show unprintable letters as a period (`.`), though your first hexeditor seems to be attempting to encode the symbols in iso-8859-1 (latin-1), which means the byte displayed as a copyright symbol is really an `A9` in hex (See: [`iso-8859-1` (`latin-1`) codepage layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout).

There are an unlimited number of ways to encrypt a file, so you can't just try all of them.  There's an infinite number of ways you can generate a key from a password (e.g., the first 128-bits of iterated 5000 rounds of a SHA-256 hash function combined using the IV as a salt), many types of encryption algorithms (AES, Serpent, Blowfish, Threefish, DES, RC5, CAST, Salsa -- and this is just for symmetric ciphers; there's also a variety of asymmetric encryption algorithms), and many tweakable settings for each type of method (key size, rounds, block size, block cipher mode (CBC, OFB, CFB, CTR, etc), where to store the IV, how to encode the data, etc.

Comment: This is unfortunate.  A guy who reportedly did a couple years of work gave this file as a result and isn't likely to respond to any questions.  I will attempt to have him reached.  And as for Kruptos 2, it does not handle this file type, nor does it recognize anything when I've attempted to open the file with it.  I've seen that some people have figured out file type with hex editors.  I was thinking we could at least figure out how many bits of encryption are involved based on the end of the file.  Thank you for your thorough insight!